# unable to update a table for some times

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

I am facing a strange behaviour in my oracle 10g DB.  Frequently I am unable to update one of my table via sql developer. When I fire "Update" Query more than 1000 Secs the query still running. The content of that table is very very less.

How can I resolve the above issue? Is there any methods.

Regards,
Jerald.

Comment: Is it possible that there is an uncommited(or rolled back) transaction, that holds row-level/table lock?

Comment: @NicholasKrasnov, May I know how can I view row-level/table lock?

Comment: The dba views `V$SESSION`, `V$TRANSACTION`, `V$LOCK` (and perhaps `V$SQL`) may be of help.

Comment: Take a look at the contents of `v$locked_object` dynamic performance view to see what session is holding `DML/SELECT..FOR UPDATE` lock on your table. if there are none, you need to provide more detailed information.

Comment: Try this query, `select username , program , sid , blocking_session , row_wait_obj# from v$session`. the last column is the object_id from dba_objects.